# Path error when edit/commit file on Gitlab site

Tags: path, gitlab, whitespace, git-commit

I'm trying to edit a .txt file on the (our) gitlab website but on commit the following error appears:

```
Path can contain only letters, digits, '_', '-', '@', '+' and '.'.
```

I guess the error is caused by a whitespace in the file name "Neues Textdokument.txt", because other files without a space in the file name are editable.

Any ideas how to fix it (gitlab-sided) or is it a "real" bug?
Pls don't advise me to remove the whitespace... ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Arunkumar 's hint. This issue is now fixed in Gitlab-CE v9.4.

See [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/12608).

Allow creating files/directories with space in the name using the web interface was the originally issue and was generalized to the topic "Make filename and path creation compatible with UNIX in web UI".

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. In my case my file name is like `read me.md`. Then I removed the space in that file name. Now I can edit the file in GitLab UI.

Check your file name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I wrote: I won't use this "workaround". I was able to push this file with git bash with a whitespace in its name, so I expect to work with it in Gitlab too ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Found the according task: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/12608